# In Scrapy, how to use nested item loaders without further 'add_xpath' calls

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to refactor a Scrapy spider making use of [Item Loaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html). I've gotten to a part where I'm populating several fields from data extracted from a single XPath expression, and for brevity I'd like to use [Nested Loaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#nested-loaders).

Here is the spider so far:

```
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from apkmirror_scraper.items import ApkmirrorScraperItem, ApkmirrorItemLoader

class ApkmirrorSitemapSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'apkmirror-spider'
    sitemap_urls = ['http://www.apkmirror.com/sitemap_index.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [(r'.*-android-apk-download/$', 'parse')]

    def parse(self, response):
        loader = ApkmirrorItemLoader(item=ApkmirrorScraperItem(), response=response)

        loader.add_value('url', response.url)
        loader.add_xpath(field_name='title', xpath='//h1[@title]/text()')
        loader.add_xpath(field_name='developer', xpath='//h3[@title]/a/text()')
        loader.add_xpath(field_name='app', xpath='//*[contains(@data-channel-name, "App Updates")]/@data-channel-name')

        apk_details_loader = loader.nested_xpath('//*[@title="APK details"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]')

        apk_details_loader.add_xpath(field_name="version_name", xpath=".//text()")
        apk_details_loader.add_xpath(field_name="version_code", xpath=".//text()")

        return loader.load_item()
```

where `items.py` is

```
import re

import scrapy
import scrapy.loader

from scrapy.loader.processors import Compose, MapCompose, TakeFirst

class ApkmirrorScraperItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    developer = scrapy.Field()
    app = scrapy.Field()
    version_name = scrapy.Field()
    version_code = scrapy.Field()
    architectures = scrapy.Field()
    package = scrapy.Field()
    apk_file_size = scrapy.Field()
    android_min_version = scrapy.Field()
    android_target_version = scrapy.Field()
    supported_dpis = scrapy.Field()
    md5_signature = scrapy.Field()
    time_uploaded = scrapy.Field()
    time_scraped = scrapy.Field()
    download_link = scrapy.Field()


def parse_app(data_channel_name):
    '''Parse the name of the app from the "data-channel-name" attribute of the button named "Follow [app_name] Updates".'''
    pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<app>.+) App Updates')
    return pattern.search(data_channel_name).groupdict().get("app")

def get_version_line(apk_details):
    '''Get the line containing the version from the 'APK details' section.'''
    return next(line for line in apk_details if line.startswith("Version:"))

def get_architectures_line(apk_details):
    '''Get the line containing the supported architectures (e.g. "arm", "x64") from the 'APK details' section, if present.'''
    return apk_details[1] if not apk_details[1].startswith("Package:") else None       # The line does not contain any keywords and may not be present, in which case None is returned

def get_package_line(apk_details):
    return next(line for line in apk_details if line.startswith("Package:"))                # The 'package line' is always present and starts with "Package:"

def parse_version_line(version_line):
    '''Parse the 'versionName' and 'versionCode' from the relevant line in 'APK details'.'''
    PATTERN = r"^Version: (?P<version_name>.+) \((?P<version_code>\d+)\)\s*$"       # Note that the pattern includes the end-of-line character ($). This is necessary because some package names (e.g. Google Play) themselves contain brackets.
    return re.match(PATTERN, version_line).groupdict()


class ApkmirrorItemLoader(scrapy.loader.ItemLoader):

    url_out = TakeFirst()

    title_in = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
    title_out = TakeFirst()

    developer_in = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
    developer_out = TakeFirst()

    app_in = MapCompose(parse_app)
    app_out = TakeFirst()

    version_name_in = Compose(get_version_line, parse_version_line, lambda d: d.get("version_name"))
    version_name_out = TakeFirst()

    version_code_in = Compose(get_version_line, parse_version_line, lambda d: d.get("version_code"))
    version_code_out = TakeFirst()
```

If I run the spider, for example, using the command

```
scrapy parse --spider=apkmirror-spider http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/sheets/sheets-1-7-152-06-release/google-sheets-1-7-152-06-30-android-apk-download/
```

It extracts the fields as expected:

```
# Scraped Items  ------------------------------------------------------------
[{'app': u'Google Sheets',
  'developer': u'Google Inc.',
  'title': u'Google Sheets 1.7.152.06.30 (arm) (nodpi)',
  'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/sheets/sheets-1-7-152-06-release/google-sheets-1-7-152-06-30-android-apk-download/',
  'version_code': u'71520630',
  'version_name': u'1.7.152.06.30'}]
```

I would like to further refactor the `apk_details_loader`, however. Notice how the two lines with `apk_details_load.add_xpath` have the same `xpath` argument, `".//text()"`. To avoid this code repetition, I would like to instead define `apk_details_loader` as

```
apk_details_loader = loader.nested_xpath('//*[@title="APK details"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]//text()')
```

including the `//text()` at the end, and instead of `add_xpath` do something like just `add`, which instead of further refining the XPath expression and then calling the input processors on them, simply calls the input processors directly. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.

You'd need to add this new method to the `ItemLoader` class in `scrapy/loader/__init__py`.

This should do it:

```py
def add(self, field_name, *processors, **kw):
    values = self.selector.extract()
    self.add_value(field_name, values, *processors, **kw)
```

**Explanation:**
`loader.nested_xpath(xpath)` does not return a special new loader; it initializes the same kind of loader you were previously using, except it initializes it with a value of `selector` set to `self.selector.xpath(xpath)` (Note that here `self` refers to the calling object, `loader`.) So, your newly created `apk_details_loader` already contains the selector from which you want to extract data. You need only reference it in the add method, which we do with the line `values = self.selector.extract()`.